# How to drop 2 columns using a single variable in Python

Tags: python

I have this code that works perfectly

```
Exclude = "A"
df = df.drop([Exclude], 1)
```

I want to drop 2 columns at the same time

but this code does not work

```
Exclude = ["A", "B"]
df = df.drop([Exclude], 1)
```

I know I can use

```
Exclude1 = "A"
Exclude2 = "B"
df = df.drop([Exclude1], 1)
df = df.drop([Exclude2], 1)
```

but this is not what I want

I want to use single variable ( and it has to be through variable)

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since,

```
Exclude="A"
df.drop(Exclude, axis=1) #works
```

then

```
Exclude=["C", "D"]
dr.drop(Exclude, axis=1) #will work also.
```

Per [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

> labels : single label or list-like

Answer (score 2):

`drop` expects a list as an input argument, so you need to write

```
Exclude = ["A", "B"]
df = df.drop(Exclude, 1)
```

since `Exclude` is already a list.

Answer (score 1):

***Change:***

```
Exclude = ["A", "B"]
df = df.drop([Exclude], 1)
```

***To:***

```
Exclude = ["A", "B"]
df = df.drop(columns=Exclude, 1)
```

Comment: df = df.drop(columns=[Exclude], 1)
                                   ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Answer (score 0):

You see when you are defining `Exclude = ["A", "B"]` and calling `df.drop([Exclude], 1)` you are actually calling `df.drop([["A", "B"]], 1)` which is a list of list. And that's not how drop works. So instead just pass `Exclude`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcde'),'B':list('ghijk'),'C':list('klmno')})
>>> Exclude = ["A", "B"]
>>> df.drop(Exclude, 1)
>>> 
   C
0  k
1  l
2  m
3  n
4  o
```